Disable specific authentification flows in Swagger UI
I am developing a quarkus application that uses a keycloak as oidc provider which works fine.
I also set up an swagger-ui page in which one can authenticate to use endpoints that require authorization.
My problem is now that quarkus, in its default configuration, shows EVERY auth flow.

I only want to show the implicit flow, the rest (like password, client_credentials, token-exchange ...) should not be displayed.
I know it is possible to configure (I use the .yaml configuration style) specific auth flows but I have not yet figured out how to set it up to only allow the specific implicit auth flow.
My best guess is that this config key is part of the solution but i have no clue on how to set it up.


Okay the solution is quite simple. To for example only allow oauth2-implicit set the security-scheme property and fill the necessary fields.
quarkus:   
  smallrye-openapi:
    security-scheme: oauth2-implicit
    oauth2-implicit-authorization-url: <host>/protocol/openid-connect/auth
    oauth2-implicit-token-url: <host>/protocol/openid-connect/token

or
quarkus.smallrye-openapi.security-scheme=oauth2-implicit
quarkus.smallrye-openapi.oauth2-implicit-authorization-url: <host>/protocol/openid-connect/auth
quarkus.smallrye-openapi.oauth2-implicit-token-url: <host>/protocol/openid-connect/token

does the trick
